# Python, Downloading files from url link csv with login

Tags: python

Currently I have a csv file with a large number of links (900+) to download files from. What I wish to do is download all the files from this csv file however in order to download the files I need to log into the website which is done by navigating to a specific page on the website of interest and logging in from there.

I can set up a login session via selenium and use repeated driver.get commands to initiate the downloads but this has a tendency to not work in my experience.

Wget is an option to retrieve the files via iterating over the links in the file but it doesn't get around the issue that the website requires a login to work.

So in short my question what is the most efficient implementation for iterating over a series of download links located in a csv file, downloading all files from said links and enabling a login session to be able to download these files?

EDIT: Currently testing with requests

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
s.get("URL of Landing page to generate cookies")
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
s.get("Login page URL")
```

Comment: Have a look at `requests.Session`, with it you can login and follow up with others downloads

Comment: I've taken a short look at it and from what I understand I need to generate a browser session which contains cookies to log into the website. Now I've done this using selenium but It doesn't help with looping over the links that I need later in the program. However using the above code I get the following error `SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)` What do you make of this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `urllib.request` module and its [HTTPBasicAuthHandler()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler) class. So you could:

```
import urllib.request as ur

mgr = ur.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
mgr.add_password(None, 'url', 'username', 'password') # where url is each url

auth = ur.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(mgr)

opener = ur.build_opener(auth)

rsp = opener.open('url/at/some/path').read()
```

However you want to iterate through the CSV to build a list of URLs and make queries is up to you.